# mvc 3.0 with wcf pass inputs from view and fetch result and bind to gridview

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf

am completely new to MVC 3.0
am asked to create a MVC 3.0 application with WCF. I have already created a WCF service and also created MVC application. Am kinda doubtful on the process of how i can link the service to the view of the MVC application. I have created a controller named TMReportController. I have a view BenchEmployee. I need to pass inputs from the View ie., i need to pass values of a dropdown to the service fetch the dataset it returns and bind it to a grid that is present in the view BenchEmployee. Do not my view is an aspx page.
can some one please explain to me how this can be done?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET MVC application will be the client of the WCF service. So the first step is to import the service definition. This will create the proxy objects on the client. So inside your MVC application you will get the operation and data contracts that are defined on the service.

Now all that's left for you is to write a view model that will reflect the requirements of your view:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Displayname("Select an item")]
    public string SelectedItemId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items 
    { 
        get
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "item 1" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "item 2" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "item 3" },
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<SomeType> Results { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        using (var client = new YourWebServiceClient())
        {
            model.Results = client.GetResults(model.SelectedItemId);
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

and finally you could have a corresponding strongly typed view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SelectedItemId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItemId, Model.Items)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}

@if (Model.Results != null)
{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model.Results);
    @grid.GetHtml();
}
```

Of course if the DropDownList values need to come from your web service as well you could have the Items property an auto-property with a setter and inside your GET and POST actions invoke the corresponding method on your WCF service to retrieve the values and bind it.

Comment: Hi Darin, thanks for the response I had made use of ViewBag.EmpBench and assigned it to my service proxy service 

 public class TMReportController : Controller
    {
        ServiceRef.TMReportWCFServiceClient obmyserv = new ServiceRef.TMReportWCFServiceClient();

        public ActionResult EmployeeBench()
        {
            ViewBag.EmpBench = obmyserv.GetBenchEmployee("All", "All", "All", "All");
            return View();
        }
}

am trying to access ViewBag.EmpBench in the view to bind to the gridview how can i do that?